# How to limit read speed from a tcp socket

Tags: c, sockets, io

I would like to read some data from server. But I want to limit the receiving speed. What is the best way to do that?

Only solution that comes to my mind is to measure how many bytes I received in a certain period of time, calculate speed and then make a decision whether or not to continue reading from socket or to stop for some time.

But I think that it would lead to the fact that for the first part of certain period of time (in which I measure amount of bytes received) speed would tend to a maximum bandwidth and then drop to zero for the remaining part of the period. But I want it to be stable.

Comment: please tag only one language in your question unless it's necessary.

Comment: Whether you read it or not the data will come to your application if socket is established, unread data will be reported on read queue as displayed by netstat command

Comment: You could buffer and just send the max speed number of packets.

Comment: Yes, now I realize that I do not control receiving itself. Maybe one can control receiving speed through controlling a tcp window? Or could I just rely on the fact that after receive buffer is be full no data is sent by a server and I can control receive speed by read speed from a socket?